# GROUP_CONCAT in Codeigniter to checkbox

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm quite new with codeigniter, now i'm learning about checkbox values.i have success saving to my database, My problem is how to insert the values from my table.

```
table1 (fc_artikel)
idartikel | judul_artikel | deskripsi | isiartikel
   18           Title           Desc       Content

table2 (fc_kategori)
idkategory| namakategory
    1           PHP
    2           HTML
table3 (fc_artikelkategori)
ID | idartikel | idkategory
 1       18         1
 2       18         2
```

It's my controller to show the article to my edit form.

```
function editartikel($id)
{
 $sql   = 
 "select a.idartikel,a.deskripsi,a.judul_artikel,a.isiartikel,b.namakategori,
 GROUP_CONCAT(b.idkategori)idkategori
  from fc_artikel a left join fc_artikelkategori c on a.idartikel=c.idartikel 
        left join fc_kategori b on b.idkategori=c.idkategori
        where a.flag='1' and c.idartikel='$id' group_by b.idkategori";
$sql1   = "select * from fc_kategori where flag='1'";
 $this->data['artikel'] = $this->bymodel->tampildata($sql);
 $this->data['kategori'] = $this->bymodel->tampildata($sql1);
$this->data['include']= 'admin/editartikel';
$this->load->view('admin/page',$this->data);    
}
```

And it's my model

```
function tampildata ($sql)
    {
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            return $query->result();
    }
```

so far i've made my view like this, and i'm stuck to insert the value from the database.

```
<?php
foreach($artikel as $baris)
{
?>
<form method='POST' action='<?=base_url();?>admin/updateartikel/<?php echo $baris->idartikel ;?>'>
    <fieldset><label>JUDUL</label><input type='text' value='<?php echo $baris->judul_artikel;?>' name='judul'></fieldset>
<textarea name="content" id="content" ><?php echo $baris->isiartikel;?></textarea>
    <?php echo display_ckeditor($ckeditor); ?>
    <fieldset>
<p>
    *<?php 
             $output[] =$baris->idkategori;
             echo implode(', ', $output);
    } 
    ?>
        <label>Kategori</label>

<?php foreach ($kategori as $pilihan){?>
    <p>
            MY CHECKBOX (VALUES FROM database)
    </p>
<?php }; ?>
</p>
```

I've try to make array from my *$baris->idkategori* but i'm failed, well it's not failed i just don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all using `GROUP_CONCAT` is not optimal solution because it has a default limit of 1024 characters  to concat from your question i guess you need to show all the categories and by default selected categories which where assigned previously to your article for this you can select all selected categories in a separate array and in loop check categories that were selected before

```
/* Controller */

function editartikel($id){
    $this->data['artikel'] = $this->bymodel->getArticle($id);
    $this->data['kategori'] = $this->bymodel->getCategories();
    $this->data['selected_kategori'] = $this->bymodel->getSelectedCategories($id);
    $this->data['include']= 'admin/editartikel';
    $this->load->view('admin/page',$this->data);    
}
```

Also move queries in your models and use active record

```
/* Model */ 

function getArticle($id){

    return $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('fc_artikel')
    ->where('flag',1)
    ->where('idartikel',$id)
    ->get()
    ->result();

}

function getCategories(){

    return $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('fc_kategori')
    ->where('flag',1)
    ->get()
    ->result();

}

function getSelectedCategories(){

    return $this->db->select('c.*')
    ->from('fc_kategori c')
    ->join('fc_artikelkategori ac','c.idkategori=ac.idkategori')
    ->where('c.flag',1)
    ->get()
    ->result();

}
```

In view part there is no sense to loop over only record if you get article by article id then it means you are selecting only one article so no need to loop over and show your article details i will show you the selected categories part

```
<?php 
$selectedids=array();
foreach ($selected_kategori as $s){

    $selectedids[] = $s->idkategory;

}
foreach ($kategori as $c){


    if(in_array($c->idkategory,$selectedids)){
    $selected ='checked="checked"';
    }else{
    $selected ='';
    }?>
     <p>
     <?php echo $c->namakategory; ?>     
     </p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="categoires[]" <?php echo $selected; ?> value="<?php echo $c->idkategory;?>" />

<?php } ?>
```

if you still want to go with you previous solution using `group_concat` so in view part you can do so

```
<p>
    <?php 

   $selectedCats= implode(',',$baris->idkategori);

   foreach ($kategori as $c){


    if(in_array($c->idkategory,$selectedCats)){
    $selected ='checked="checked"';
    }else{
    $selected ='';
    }?>
     <p>
     <?php echo $c->namakategory; ?>     
     </p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="categoires[]" <?php echo $selected; ?> value="<?php echo $c->idkategory;?>" />

<?php } ?>

</p>
```

Comment: limit of 1024 characters ? sorry ,where did you find the information?. I should learn more. btw your script is work thanks

Comment: @Bossby you can find this information on mysql docs [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in description section they have described also how to overcome this limit issue